# Display png images like charts in HTML / CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I have made a bunch of charts and tables which I have saved in png format for presentation as stimuli in a web-based experiment created with HTML / CSS / Javascript. How can I get them to look sharp when displayed?

Here's a sample of what they look like now when displayed in the experiment:

[image: sample]

As you can see, the lines are jagged and sometimes even thin to vanishing, and the text has similar problems. I guess this is a consequence of the png images' "natural" sizes (about 3500x2500 pix) being larger than their display sizes (about 200px high), but I feel there should be some way to fix this at display time without manually resizing all the images.

Here's some history: these were all made in Excel, then copied to Powerpoint and thence saved as images. Originally I directly saved from Powerpoint, which defaulted to .jpg format and came out fuzzy. Then I tried saving to .emf and used IrfanView to resave as .png. The resulting pngs are extremely sharp when viewed in their natural (large) size through whatever image viewer, but when I embed them in html at a much smaller size, they look pretty bad as shown above.

Comment: What's the dimension of the images (in px)?

Comment: If you want an image to stay crisp when resizing, you should use a vector graphic format rather than a bitmap.

Comment: I just added the pix dimensions to my question. I'll look into vector graphic format - don't know what it is but I'm sure I can find it - thanks!

Comment: OK, it looks like finding the right vector graphic format that can be displayed easily and across browsers is also not a trivial question ... any recommendation for that?

Comment: Not a programming answer but, if you have Photoshop you could resize a batch of images using "Image Processor" under File->Scripts

Answer (score 1):

Do you still have the excel file? If so you can:

1. Export your charts as pdf files in excel;
2. Then import the pdf's into a vector program such as Inkscape;
3. Save as `svg` and then reference the `svg` files like you would do with an image
   tag(you can also embed directly)

When importing as a pdf they will be vector graphics so you can edit some points further if needed.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard for a line on the screen to look good with a less that 1 pixel thickness.

So let's say you have elements 3 pixels thick on your image. After resizing to 250 X 250, they would be 0.3 pixels thick -> not good.

That what creates the undesirable effects you described at line edges and corners.

To address that problems I see three potential solutions:

- Make an other copy of the images with lower resolutions from the original source (like screenshot of the Excel charts, or any other features that allows you to get a low resolution bitmap)
- If you have the numerical data displayed on the charts and time to learn a cool technology, you can use a charting library. This way you would get the prettier rendering, because it would be vector drawings. Example: [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
- Last and far worse solution: work on the images with an image editor and the appropriate skills to increase the thickness size of all sharp elements, like lines, dots, arrows, etc...